# getUserMedia() audio fails in static website after working in sdk

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, getusermedia

**2 new important facts here**

- [As stated in this Google App Engine page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) **no app.yaml** file is employed.  **As mentioned in the Answer, app.yaml is in fact required, duh.**
- [contracalls.appspot.com] **works** when I launch it from my own Mac `Terminal` from within it's own directory as follows
  `server:contracalls brian$ gcloud app browse --project contracalls`
  But, of course, others can't launch from my desktop computer, so I still need a fix. [Are the instructions at the Google App Engine page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) incomplete, perhaps?

**jsfiddle.net added**
[This shows a working jsfiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/jr4dge5b/1/)

Line 3 of the following code produces `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined`  [when deployed here](http://contracalls.appspot.com), but works fine in the GAE sdk. (You can try the link yourself.) Any ideas?

Index.js:

```
const recordAudio = () =>
new Promise(async resolve => {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        let audioChunks = [];
// ...
});
```

Notice:

- This is a static website application with only html and javascript employed.
- Using Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: You may want to update your post again - the .yaml file is needed, even for local operation...

Answer (score 1):

I chatted and then emailed with a Google support professional who finally figured out the problem (see below). Along the way I discovered that contrary to my updated question, there **is** an app.yaml file as was described at the first link in the question.

The problem was that the app must be called with http`s`:// and to force that I needed to place `secure: always` in the app.yaml file.